# How do I enable Jaeger JDBC tracing in Quarkus

Tags: java, jdbc, quarkus, jaeger

How do I enable `Jaeger jdbc` tracing in `Quarkus`? I've followed the `Quarkus` guides for `Opentracing` and didn't see any info about this.

I'm using `Quarkus` v0.21.2 with the following extensions:

```
 -quarkus-smallrye-opentracing
 -quarkus-resteasy
 -quarkus-resteasy-jackson
 -quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache
 -quarkus-jdbc-postgresql
 -quarkus-smallrye-openapi
```

And my code is just a basic Rest endpoint which calls my entity's Panache CRUD operation.

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried the following and it didn't work:

```
 - added @Traced to my entity
 - changed quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=const into quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=remote
```

What I expect in `Jaeger` is, 2 spans for 1 trace, one for the REST call and another one for the `JDBC` call.

But what I see is just 1 span for the REST call.

Comment: Currently I don't believe we have any OpenTracing JDBC libraries in Quarkus.

Please raise an issue to support this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: Did you try to use https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-jdbc ?
If it didn't works OOTB, maybe an extension needs to be created in Quarkus tu support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use opentracing [java-jdbc](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-jdbc) extension  it will works in Quarkus (I didn't test the native mode).

You need to use the version 0.0.12 as the latest one is based on Opentracing 0.33 but Quarkus use the version 0.31.

1. Add the dependency to your pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
     <artifactId>opentracing-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.12</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Update your application.properties to use the opentracing-jdbc driver, the following are for a Postgres database:

```
quarkus.datasource.url = jdbc:tracing:postgresql://localhost:5433/mydatabase
quarkus.datasource.driver = io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

You will then saw the SQL queries in Jaeger as spans.

Comment: thx for the fast reply. This indeed works. I was using version 0.1.8 of opentracing-jdbc and this wasn't working.

Comment: maybe an idea to add this automatically in Quarkus, if the project contains any jdbc/jpa dependencies when also adding quarkus.opentracing in your project ?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good idea to automatically add it because it creates a lot of spans and not eveybody should need it.
What can be done is to write a section in the guide about it and manage the version in the Quarkus bom to avoid a developer to spent time finding the version that works. I can take care of it