# quarkus reactive-postgresql-client with jaeger opentracing support

Tags: quarkus, opentracing, jaeger

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854200/how-do-i-enable-jaeger-jdbc-tracing-in-quarkus) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072395/quarkus-log-tracing-and-equivalent-to-spring-cloud-sleuth)

How would I enable tracing for [reactive-sql-clients](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients) ?

Now use `%dev.quarkus.datasource.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://dev-db-server:5432/mydb` - it works, but no tracing support though. I can see racing for my rest calls but not the db.

Tried to use `%dev.quarkus.datasource.url=vertx-reactive:tracing:postgresql://dev-db-server:5432/mydb`

my deps:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see..

I thought **@Traced** will be somehow propagated to my db-services/repositories. No, I have to put it explicitly:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.opentracing.Traced;

@Traced        // << -- here it is
@Singleton
public class MarketPgRepository implements MarketRepository {

    @Inject
    PgPool client;
```

That fixes the issue.

Comment: By default only JAX-RS Resource methods have @Traced implied, every other method needs to explicitly include it. At least for now